# Check if it absolutely converges or not

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to determine if $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(n\pi + \frac{1}{2n})$ absolutely converges or not.

Help me check it. I don't know how to do it. Advance thanks. :)

Comment: \frac{1}{2n}
 Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $n>0$

$\sin(n\pi+\frac{1}{2n})=(-1)^n\sin(\frac{1}{2n})$

and

$$|\sin(n\pi+\frac{1}{2n})|=\sin(\frac{1}{2n}).$$

but

$$\sin(\frac{1}{2n})=\frac{1}{2n}(1+(2n\sin(\frac{1}{2n})-1))$$

$$=\frac{1}{2n}(1+\epsilon(n))$$ with

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\epsilon(n)=0.$$

thus for large enough $n$,

$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2n}<\sin(\frac{1}{2n})$$

and by comparison with harmonic series, $$\sum \sin(\frac{1}{2n})$$ is divergent.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have edited my post and (+1) for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Observe
\begin{align}
\sin\left(n\pi +\frac{1}{2n}\right) = (-1)^n\sin\frac{1}{2n}
\end{align}
then apply alternating series test.

It should be noted for large enough $n$ the terms $\sin\frac{1}{2n}$ decreases monotonically to zero.

Hence the series converges conditionally.

Edit: Let us consider the case of absolute convergence. Observe
\begin{align}
\sin x = x-\frac{x^3}{3!} +\mathcal{O}(x^5)
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\sin x \geq x-\frac{x^3}{3!}
\end{align}
for a neigbhorhood close to $0$. Hence it follows
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=N} \sin \frac{1}{2n} \geq \sum^\infty_{n=N} \frac{1}{2n} -\frac{1}{3!}\sum^\infty_{n=N} \frac{1}{8 n^3} 
\end{align}
which shows that the series diverges absolutely because $\sum^\infty_{n=N} \frac{1}{n} = \infty$.

Comment: The question is about absolute convergence.

Comment: You did a good job at answering a wrong question :)

Comment: @Wojowu I think it's a habit. I'm kind of absent-minded.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, perhaps simpler but I think that shorter anyway: the limit comparison theorem with $\;b_n=\frac1{2n}\;$ , then

$$\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{\sin\frac1{2n}}{\frac1{2n}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$$

and thus the series $\;\sum\sin\frac1{2n}\;,\;\;\sum\frac1{2n}\;$ converge or diverge together...but the latter is just a constant multiple of the harmonic one.

Comment: That is what i did friend DonAntonio.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam No, you didn't at all. Your last step is direct comparison using a function $\;\epsilon(n)\;$ which comes from another limit.

Comment: Didn't you see  what is $\epsilon(n)$ in my answer.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Of course: it is $\;\epsilon (n)=2n\sin\frac1{2n}-1\;$ ...so what? This approaches zero, that's a basic, elementary limit, which then allowed you to use direct comparison test, as opposed to the **limit** comparison test (google it) I use above.

Comment: If you don't know it, The limit comparison test  comes from the direct comparison one.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam No, it doesn't.  That would be like saying that the $\;n\,-$ th root test comes or yields the quotient test: they are different ones. Of course, we *use* the direct comparison test to prove the limit comparison test ...  Didn't you google it as I adviced you? Take a peek at  http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SeriesCompTest.aspx , and you will be able to see it is a separate test, and sometimes very useful as it allows you to prove convergence/divergence faster/easier than other tests. You can also read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Any time.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $|\sin(n\pi +{1\over2n})| = \sin({1\over2n}) \sim {1\over2n}$ and therefore $\sum \sin(n\pi +{1\over2n})$ is absolutely divergent (because $\sum{1\over n}$ is)